# Element id not changing

Tags: javascript, html, css

I have a id change bound to a key, but for someone reason it consistently fails to run - despite other changes run inside the keybinding working perfectly, and the code used to change the id is the same as functional code elsewhere in the program.

Relevant code:

```
var KeyBind = function() {
    if (document.addEventListener) {
        document.addEventListener("keydown", keyDownHandler, false);
        document.addEventListener("keydown", keyUpHandler, false);
    }
    else if (document.attachEvent) {
        document.attachEvent("onkeydown", function() {
            keyDownHandler(window.event);
        });
        document.attachEvent("onkeydown", function() {
            keyUpHandler(window.event);
        });
    }

    function keyDownHandler(e) {
        var key = e.which || e.keyCode
        if (key == "50"){
            document.getElementById('Player').id='PlayerLeft';
            document.getElementById('PlayerLeft').style.webkitAnimationPlayState="running";
            setTimeout(function(){
                document.getElementById('PlayerLeft').style.webkitAnimationPlayState="paused";
            }, 200);
        }

        if (key == "49"){
            document.getElementById('PlayerLeft').style.webkitAnimationPlayState="running";
            setTimeout(function(){
                document.getElementById('PlayerLeft').style.webkitAnimationPlayState="paused";
            }, 800);                
        };

        if (key == "57"){
            //setTimeout(function(){
            document.getElementById('PlayerLeft2').style.webkitAnimationPlayState="running";
            //}, 800);

            setTimeout(function(){
                document.getElementById('PlayerLeft2').style.webkitAnimationPlayState="paused";
            }, /*1*/350);

            /*setTimeout(function(){
                document.getElementById('PlayerLeft2').style.webkitAnimationPlayState="running";
            }, 1150);

            setTimeout(function(){
                document.getElementById('PlayerLeft2').id='Player';                 
            }, 1500);*/         
        };

        if (key == "57" && document.getElementById('PlayerLeft2').style.left>="681px"){
            document.getElementById('PlayerLeft2').style.webkitAnimationPlayState="running";
            var idChanger = function(){
                document.getElementById('PlayerLeft2').id='Player';
            };
            setTimeout(//function(){                    
                idChanger
            /*}*/, 100);
        };                                                                              
    };
}();
```

Jsfiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/6JUaB/

Comment: Maybe this is only a typo in your post, but there's no eventlisteners for `onkeyup` events at all. Both listeners are for  `keydown` only, in the code for IE and other browsers as well.

Comment: Is there a particular reason why you're changing the ID?  Just looking at the code you've posted, you'd get exactly the same results if you just left the ID the same throughout.  IDs are supposed to be unique references, changing them isn't a common pattern, it's likely you'll run into some uncommon edge cases and race conditions.

Comment: The id changes are so I can transition between animations - the ship's movement is a stack of CSS3 keyframe animations. The onkeyup events are gone because the code seems to run fine 99% of the time without them, and I would prefer 1 out of every 100 tries failed than writing and testing another 200 lines of keybindings.

Comment: You don't need to change the id to transition between animations.  If you have multiple different animations you want to run on a single element, add them to class names not to ids.  BTW, your JS Fiddle tells me 'This page is incompatible with IE' even though I'm not using IE.

Comment: Yeah, I can't be bothered specifying it to IE so I just put the alert at the top of the document. On another note, wouldn't you still need to transition between classes to shift betwen animations?

Comment: I'm not using IE, I still get the alert.  It's hard for me to tell whether you need to transition between classes because I couldn't get your example to do anything.

Comment: You click the alert away, start the game, then attempt to move the keys with 2 and 1 (left of centre) and 0, 9 (left of far right). I already explained why it didn't care what browser you are using - it isn't set to check the browser.

Comment: I fixed the problem - thanks for UX feedback :D